# How to point AWS Route 53 to wordpress.com blog?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a website that I serve out of AWS. The domain name is www.my-website-blah.com.

Now, I created a wordpress blog: my-website-blah.wordpress.com.

I want the blog to appear at blog.my-website-blah.com.

How do I do it?

I believe to do it, I have to setup a NS record in Route53. However, I'm not sure what FQDNs to point them to. Where can I get that information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your domain name registry that contains your domain (eg `example.com`), create a `CNAME` record to point `blog.example.com` to `xyz.wordpress.com`.

If your domain name is registered in Route 53, then [Create the `CNAME` Resource Record Set by Using the Amazon Route 53 Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html).

If your domain name is registered somewhere else (eg GoDaddy), create the CNAME record there.